# ¿Como puedo conocer el origen de una segmentación en excel?

Tags: excel

Tengo un fichero con gran cantidad de tablas dinamicas y pestañas. En una de las tablas existe una segmentación de datos pero soy incapaz de ver de donde viene esa segmentación. He visto el campo que coge para la segmentación, pero no lo localizo, existe alguna forma de verlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. El campo de segmentación debe formar parte de los datos de origen de la tabla dinámica. ¿No te sale ahí?

Comment: OK. Pues nada mañana Le doy otro vistazo.. Habían varios orígenes de datos y no he visto ningún campo con la denominación de la segmentación. Seguro que la segmentación sólo se puede hacer sobre campos de la propia TD?